# send mail to non-registered user (email list) in a queue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to program a Laravel mailing list with a queue Try to send emails to Non-users, I did a good job with registered users and this is my code:

```
        foreach ($emails as  $i=>$item){
            $user = User::where('email',$item)->first();
            if ($i % $mailsCount == 0)$count++;
            if ($user){
                $thisBody = ElzahabyDynamicLaravelString($user,$body,$this->sign);
                $thisSubject = ElzahabyDynamicLaravelString($user,$subject,$this->sign);
                $when = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($every*$count);
                Mail::to($user)
                    ->later($when,new EmailForQueuing($user,$thisBody,$thisSubject,$request->emailTemplate));
            }
        }
```

You can **notice** `later()` method, which is responsible for the queue.  but this only works with `Mail::to` method which only works for registered users.

So, any idea how to send a mailing list with a `queue` to non-registered emails.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit 1

`EmailForQueuing()` method is a simple [`Mailable`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#configuring-the-sender) class

Comment: where do you keep non-registered users ? How do you distinguish registered/unregistered users ? I don't recommend you to query database inside for/foreach loop. You may get them with `whereIn` in a single call (depends on your `$emails`) size.

Comment: non-registered users(emails) are coming form HTML input form and separate in an array , like `['email1@com','email2@com','email3@com','etc.com']` @Ersoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was in the `Mail::to()` method is that it requires `name` and `email`.
But I was just sending the email, and I don't have any names!

so
what I did is:

make an object includes `[emails(required),name(required),any other thing(optional)]`

```
$user = (object)[
    'email' => $email,
    'name' => substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@')), // here we take the name form email (string before "@")
];
```

then send it normally:

```
$when = Carbon::now()->addMinutes($every*$count);
Mail::to($user)->later($when,new EmailForQueuing($user,$thisBody,$thisSubject,$request->emailTemplate));
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `fill` method to create an instance of User without `saving` into the database it such as;

```
$mailUser = (new User())->fill(['email' => 'something@foo.bar']);
```

You may pass also other fields such as `['name' => 'some name', 'age' => 23]`

Another option without using the fill would be

```
$mailUser = (new User(['email' => 'something@foo.bar']))
```

Your code will be something like this;

```
$mails = ['email1@com', 'email2@com', 'email3@com', 'etc.com'];
$users = [];

foreach ($mails as $mail) {
    $users[] = (new User(['email' => $mail]));
}

return $users;
```

Comment: **ERROE:** `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Auth\User]`

Comment: It is probably trying to fetch user model inside the job/mail class. If the class giving error has `SerializesModels` trait, could you remove and try again @A.El-zahaby -- you may need to queue:restart after the change.